# Scraping - Loading dynamic buttons

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to web-scrape the "Fresh & Chilled" products of [Waitrose & Partners](https://www.waitrose.com/ecom/shop/browse/groceries/fresh_and_chilled) using Ruby and Nokogiri.

In order to load more products, I'd need to click in 'Load More...', which will dynamically load more products without altering the URL or redirecting to a new page.

How do I 'click' the "Load More" button to load more products?

[image]

I think it is a dynamic website as  items are loaded dynamically after clicking the "Load More..." button and the URL is not being altered at all (so no pagination is visible)

Here's the code I've tried so far, but I'm stuck in loading more items. My guess is that the DOM is being loaded by itself, but you cannot actually click the button because it represents to call a javascript method which will load the rest of the items.

```
require "csv"
require "json"
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"
require "pry"

def scrape_category(category)
  CSV.open("out/waitrose_items_#{category}.csv", "w") do |csv|
    headers = [:id, :name, :category, :price_per_unit, :price_per_quantity, :image_url, :available, :url]
    csv << headers
    url = "https://www.waitrose.com/ecom/shop/browse/groceries/#{category}"
    html = open(url)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
    load_more = doc.css(".loadMoreWrapper___UneG1").first
    pages = 0
    while load_more != nil
      puts pages.to_s
      load_more.content # Here's where I don't know how to click the button to load more items
      products = doc.css(".podHeader___3yaub")
      puts "products = " + products.length.to_s
      pages = pages + 1

      load_more = doc.css(".loadMoreWrapper___UneG1").first
    end
    (0..products.length-1).each do |i|
      puts "url = " + products[i].text
    end
    load_more = doc.css(".loadMoreWrapper___UneG1")[0]

    # here goes the processing of each single item to put in csv file
  end
end

def scrape_waitrose
  categories = [
    "fresh_and_chilled",
  ]

  threads = categories.map do |category|
    Thread.new { scrape_category(category) }
  end

  threads.each(&:join)

end

#binding.pry
```

Comment: Your question is poorly asked. We need to see evidence of your effort. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. Is the page DHTML or static? If it's static Nokogiri is great for scraping, but Mechanize would be the better tool.

Comment: So you have absolutely zero code showing what you've tried so far? Nothing at all to indicate you've tried to do this on your own first? Not even one line of code as a starting point?

Comment: "I could have spent hours researching about all these topics, but isn't this what the community is for?" Nope. SO isn't a site to do the research for you; SO is the site of last resort. I'd highly recommend reading the following page; It's long but thorough and is recommended often: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I have no doubt that this question would already be closed if not for the bounty on it. I suggest you read the links in the first comment and update this post to meet at least the minimum required content for questions here.

Comment: @Antonio - that javascript method will likely be making an Ajax call - if you can get the URL that the ajax call is making, perhaps you can make that call yourself: provided of course, the server doesn't restrict you from making the calls yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri is a way of parsing HTML. It's the Ruby equivalent to Javascript's Cheerio or Java's Jsoup. This is actually not a Nokogiri question.

What you are confusing is the way to parse the HTML and the method to collect the HTML, as delivered over the network. It is important to remember that lots of functions, like your button clicking, are enabled by Javascript. These days many sites, like React sites, are completely built by Javascript.

So when you execute this line:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

It is the html variable you have to concentrate on. Your html is **NOT** the same as the html that I would view from the same page in my browser.

In order to do any sort of reliable web scraping, you **have** to use a headless browser that will execute Javascript files. In Ruby terms, that used to mean using Poltergeist to control Phantomjs, a headless version of the Webkit browser. Phantomjs became unsupported when Puppeteer and headless Chrome arrived.

Comment: Thanks @Tom for you response. That gave me a lot of guidance. So are you suggesting to use Puppeteer in NodeJS?

Comment: Hi sorry for late response. I don't do much in Ruby these days, is there a Puppeteer gem? If not, then Node is the way to do it. My experience of Node vs Ruby was very positive and Puppeteer has a huge user community now. If you think the answer helped, accept or upvote for future visitors?

Comment: thanks for your answer and explanation. I'll switch to Node. The bounty already expired, sorry I couldn't give it to you :(